# JS filter array on key

Tags: javascript, arrays

So an example could be:

```
let a = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80];
let b = [1,2,6];
console.log([a[1], a[2], a[6]);
```

which an explanation can be something like: get the objects of `a` which index is in `b`.

I know that i can do something like

```
const f = (a, b) => {
    let result = [];
    b.forEach(element => {
        result.push(a[element]);
    });
    return result;
}
```

But maybe there is a more concise way

EDIT: so far the best i can get is this

```
a.filter((n, index)=>b.includes(index)));
```

but is not the same, infact if `b = [0,0,0]` it does not returns `[a[0],a[0],a[0]]` but `[a[0]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterate array `b` with `Array.map()` and return the value at the respective `index` from array `a`:

```js
const a = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80];
const b = [1,2,6];

const result = b.map(index => a[index]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `.from` method of the global `Array` object lets you transform an array into a new array in a manner similar to `.map()`.

```js
let a = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80];
let b = [1,2,6];

let result = Array.from(b, n => a[n]);

console.log(result);
```

Because you want to convert `b` from indexes into values with a 1 to 1 relationship, some sort of "mapping" operation is what you're generally after.

Answer (score 2):

Another way could be:

```js
var out = [];
for(let x of b){
  out.push(a[x]);
}
```